# ExpressionEngine File Caching being cleared before scheduling

Tags: cache, caching, cache-breaking

We are experiencing some performance issues with our website and on investigation it appears that the our caching mechanism doesn't seem to be working.

For example, Template A loads Template B as an embed (embed=""). Template B is not directly accessible via the website, ie its just meant to be an embed file not a full web page.

Template B has been set to **Enable Cache** with a **Refresh Interval of 525600** (1 year). When I clear the cache and load Template B via the browser it takes 60+ seconds to load (which is why I have it cached). On a new page load it's down to 0.1 seconds. Perfect.

However I come back the next day and the page is loading at 60+ seconds again. This would suggest that the cache is being cleared for some reason even though it's not set to expire for 1 year and no one has been in to the control panel to edit any content, which would bust the cache.

Has anyone experienced this issue, or can suggest any solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don't want to update Template B dynamically (i.e. one year cache life) it might be easier to use a static cache for the Template B output.  [Stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash) provides simple static caching which you can control on a per-template basis (i.e. set only your Template B to static cache) and coexists nicely with other forms of caching (e.g. EE native).